# Elegant way to send m2m_changed signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have `RelatedModel` which has a `OneToOne Field` to the `MainModel`. It also has some normal Fields and a `ManyToMany Field` and.

When I change the `RelatedModel` it updates the `MainModel`. It updates some `ManyToMany Fields` and some normal fields.

When `RelatedModel` and the `MainModel` are linked with the `OneToOne Field` everything works fine:
It updates normal fields and m2m fields easy with the `post_save` and `m2m_changed` signals.

Where I struggle:
First I create a `RelatedModel` and the `MainModel`. Later I add a link between the models and the `RelatedModel` should update the `MainModel`.

The moment they are linked together the `post_save` signal is triggered to update all the normal fields. But the `m2m_changed` signal is not triggered. So the m2m field on the `MainModel` is never updated.

I tried hacking this by manually changing the m2m to `[]` and setting it back. But it makes extra db_calls and it doesn't even work when the m2m field is `[]` to start with.

I am looking for an elegant way to send an `m2m_changed` signal? Or call the function that is decorated with m2m?

I would love to see both even if it is for educational purposes. Or maybe a 3rd way?

Comment: I would strongly advise not to use signals, unless as last resort: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html (disclosure: I'm the author of this article).

Comment: I agree with above comment. Signals are hard to debug, because they are hidden side effect of some other action. If you are using API calls to update your models then just put the logic there in the plain sight or in the queryset manager

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem very interesting articles on your site. Though I think it wont be able to eliminate signals in my project. Its pretty complex since there are multiple ChildModels that point to 1 ParentModel. If 1 of the child objects change, the parent gets updated. Almost all fields are recalculated even some Foreign Key that have to be analyzed. So it seems objects.annotate is to basic. Also I have incoming API calls, and Django commands that change children. So the integrating logic in view/form want get me all the way.